# Can I set the visibility of a TTextBox in a function?

Tags: php, prado

I tried

```
function hilfe() {
    $this->hilfe_txt->Visible->true;
}
```

to set the visibility of

```
<com:TTextBox id="hilfe_txt" Visible="false" Text""/>
```

error is: [Notice] Trying to get property of non-object

Any ideas to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
$this->hilfe_txt->Visible=true;
```

Simple but took a long time to find.